# FB tab application opens in new window, not in iframe [Firefox 6]

Tags: facebook, iframe

My Facebook iframe app acts weird in Firefox 6. When you click bookmark on the left, the app opens in new browser tab instead of being displayed in an iframe. In other browsers (IE 7+, Chrome and Firefox 3.6, 4 & 5) everything works pretty fine.

Here's the link:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/TestPage/159257547490048

Click the "TESTAPP" link to see it in action. Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an http header to redirect to the php sdk generated login url. I ran into the same issue today. Try the following instead...

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user)
{
     // User is logged in
}
else
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

    die('<script>window.top.location.href = "' . $login_url . '";</script>');
}
```

**Edit:** for reference, I'm using php sdk 3.1.1

Comment: Actually, i'm not sending any HTTP headers. All redirections are done with JS (except for one, already tried changing it from PHP header() function to JS window.location.href). Any other ideas?

Comment: @forkie It was using a header-redirect/not-targeting-top-level-window when I tested. It seems to be working now (on win7 64bit, ff6). Try clearing cache and restarting ff.

Comment: I had tried your suggestions, but it still didn't work properly. After the latest update of Firefox everything works fine. Thank you anyway for tips.

Comment: @forkie thats odd, glad they fixed it quickly. there are still bugs from ff5.0 that have yet to be squashed :/.